# SGA: Are the Wraith vampires?

Tags: stargate, vampire, stargate-atlantis, mythology, wraiths

The connection is rather obvious.   The Wraith are nearly immortal and suck the life out of humans.  Of course there are also differences from classical vampire lore.

The following two articles connect the Wraith to vampires:

- [Wraith Be Dead?](http://www.gateworld.net/opinion/columns/stargatemythology/wraith_be_dead.shtml)
  which appears to have been written very close to the premiere of SGA
- [vampires.wikia.com](http://vampires.wikia.com/wiki/Wraith_(Stargate)) which describes the Wraith as "race of Psi-vampires that can give and take life force by pressing their hand against someone's chest, causing them to age"

The supposed history is that the Wraith defeated the Lanteans (Ancients) 10,000 years ago via siege and overwhelming numbers, and that some of the Ancients ascended and others fled back to Earth.    So the premise is there that the mythology of vampires could have originated in Wraith legend.   This also agrees with Stargate's m.o. that mythology on Earth originates in real aliens or vice versa.

So now the question:
Aside from everything cited above, is there direct evidence in the scripts or in statements by producers or writers that they either were inspired by or intended the Wraith to be related to Earth vampire mythology?

Answer (score 5):

I've been unable to find any direct quotes from episodes or interviews that would indicate the Wraith are the basis for vampire mythology on Earth. However, as you stated, that is most likely the intent of the show's creators. At one point Sheppard (or was it McKay?) refers to them as "space vampires", but in-universe that comment would obviously have been influenced by centuries of vampire lore here on Earth.

The show HAS stated in-universe that other Earth mythology originated with the Lanteans who escaped to Earth, so it's highly possible that vampires are no different.

As luck would have it, I'm currently running through Atlantis in the evenings. I'm midway through season 3 at the moment, so I may have a better answer sometime in the next week or two.

Comment: I'm about half a season behind you :) .   Good mention on the "space vampires".    My personal belief is that (a) theyintended the connection and (b) they decided not to mention it explicitly because it would be kind of hokey....   what's next, then go to a planet of werewolf aliens... I mean Mitch Pileggi was good but...

Comment: Roswell Conspiracies, fantastic show:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roswell_Conspiracies:_Aliens,_Myths_and_Legends